# How can I upgrade all my Pages '09 documents to Pages '13?

Tags: pages, iwork

I have a very substantial body of Pages 09 documents that I work on.  I've upgraded to Pages '13 recently.  Now, every time I open one of those old documents to work on it, I am greeted with the following dialog upon my first keypress:

[image]

Is there any way to mass upgrade them?  Or to default this behavior to "Upgrade Already!!"

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this by doing the following steps:

1. Create a new pages document, and just throw in whatever text. Save it.
2. A .pages file is actually a .zip file, so right click on that and unzip it.
3. In your 09 pages file, right click and select "Show Package Contents"
4. Copy everything from the Index directory of your 09 pages doc to the Index directory of the new one.
5. Zip up your new one, the one you unzipped and copied in the 09 index files.
6. Rename the zip file you just created with a .pages extension
7. Open in pages.

Comment: I think they're asking if they can do it en-masse: the current method works but is slow.

Comment: That doesn't make it a wrong answer. You could create a script to go through these steps, I don't think it deserves a down vote.

Comment: Then such a script should be implemented. It's not directly wrong, but for someone without skill, it's not helpful.

Comment: "It's not helpful" It literally shows the user how to solve their problem. I don't know how to write a script for it but I worked hard to come to this solution for myself. I decided to post it here to help this and other users dealing with this problem. It's better that I keep my mouth shut because I'm not a Unix programmer?